# Call java application launched from another container

Tags: java, docker, jar

Here's situation. I have one container with php code and php-fpm - this is my application container. Sometimes main application calls java application - jar file. So I decided to split those technologies and make seperate java container with this java application. Now I need a way to call jar file launched inside another container. One way is rebuilding java applicaton to support REST api, but it takes time so is there any other possibility to solve this problem?

Comment: It not clear how the main application calls the jar file.

Comment: It's PHP, so it just utilizes shell exec method or similar.

Comment: So, Does your jar file not work as service now?

Comment: No, it's just simple console app

Comment: An how do you read the output of java -jar execution. Via stdout?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention, it spits json response. I just call it with several params.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at Java Remote Method Invocation (Java RMI), but to be honest, I have no idea if it's possible to to this invocation not using java.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/hello/hello-world.html

Comment: If it's not a rule to be in jar form only, if there is any other form to which I could build java app and docker will be able to run it I'll gladly use it.